# Div background color spilling

Tags: html, css

[image: issue]For the div "section1" - I am trying to position it in such a way that the green color does not spill  over the div "Lnav". Is there anyway that i can adjust the CSS so that the green background color only covers the header "h1" ( just the font )? thanks

```
#Lnav
{
 line-height:30px;
 background-color:#eeeeee;
 height:300px;
 width:100px;
 float:left;
 padding:5px;
 margin:20px;
}

#section
{
 width:850px;
 float:center;
 padding:5px;
}

#section1
{
 float:center;
 padding:5px;
 background-color:lime; 

}

div id="section">
 <div id="section1">
  <h1><London></h1>
   <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="Lnav">
 <div id="LnavContents1">
    London<br>
    Chicago<br>
    Bombay<br>
 </div>
 <div id="LnavContents2">
    London<br>
    Chicago<br>
    Bombay<br>
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]</div>

</div>
```

Comment: i just got an idea - perhaps i could place the divs "section" and "Lnav" within a parent div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-left:20px` to the `#section1` CSS style to push the left edge of the green in as much as the nav section is away from the left edge.

Comment: you are right - i shall accept your answer in a few mins.

Comment: couldnt you place "section1" and "Lnav" within its oown div too?